Solflare wallet suspiciously attempts to reconnect whenever the account status changes
everyone.
I have noticed some suspicious behavior of solflare wallet.
After I connect solflare to the website, it reconnects doubtfully again and again.
I think reconnecting is triggered after target account state is changed.(But I'm not sure it is.)
Why is this happened?
Is it caused by solflare itself? or my code issue?
Anyone please tell me why it is happened.

Have you checked on whether you clicked on the Auto-connect checkmark on Solflare?


Yes, I checked auto-connect, so after being disconnected, it attempts to reconnect, which is causing this, I think.
